# React Native UI components: RCTBubblingEventBlock/RCTDirectEventBlock do not seem to work

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

I have a custom native view within an [`Ignite`](https://infinite.red/ignite) project. I am trying to set up a communication from `Objective-C` to `React Native`. The communication from `React Native` to `iOS` works with the `HTML` injection, but not the other way around. I have tried using both `RCTBubblingEventBlock` and `RCTDirectEventBlock`, but neither work. Here is the entirety of my implementation. I have changed the names of the components of course, and just left the essential implementation for your understanding of what has been done so far:

`Objective-C` code:

```
// CustomViewManager.h

#import "RCTViewManager.h"

@interface CustomViewManager : RCTViewManager

@end


// CustomViewManager.m

#import "CustomViewManager.h"
#import "CustomView.h"

#import "RCTBridge.h"
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"
#import "UIView+React.h"

@implementation CustomViewManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(htmlInjection, NSString)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(onEventA, RCTDirectEventBlock)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(onEventB, RCTDirectEventBlock)

- (UIView *) view {
  return [CustomView new];
}

@end

// CustomView.h

#import "RCTView.h"

@interface CustomView : RCTView

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *htmlInjection;
@property (nonatomic, copy) RCTDirectEventBlock onEventA;
@property (nonatomic, copy) RCTDirectEventBlock onEventB;

@end

// CustomView.m

#import "CustomView.h"
#import "RCTUtils.h"

#import "RCTBridge.h"
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"
#import "UIView+React.h"
#import "MyExternalComponent.h"

@interface CustomView () <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView* webView;

@end


- (void) setUpWebView {
  if (!_webView) {
    [self setWebView: [UIWebView new]];
    _webView.delegate = self;
    [self addSubview:_webView];
  }
}

- (instancetype)init
{
  self = [super init];
  [self setUpWebView];
  return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    [self setUpWebView];
  }
  return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
  if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
    [self setUpWebView];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void) layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews];
  CGRect frame = self.frame;
  self.webView.frame = frame;
}

#pragma mark - External methods.

- (void) setHtmlInjection:(NSString *)html {
  [_webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}

#pragma mark - Non-React component methods.

- (void) fetchData {
    [MyExternalComponent getData:^(NSString *dataA, NSError *error){
            if(error) {
                NSLog(@"Here be errors: %@", error);
                _onEventB(@{@"myError": error.localizedDescription});
            } else {
                _onEventA(@{@"myData": dataA});
            }
        }]
}

@end
```

`React Native` `JavaScript` code:

```
// MyCustomView.js

import React from 'react';
import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';

class MyCustomView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._onEventA= this._onEventA.bind(this);
    this._onEventB= this._onEventB.bind(this);
  }
  _onEventA(event: Event) {
    if (!this.props.onEventA) {
      return;
    }
    this.props.onEventA(event.nativeEvent.myData);
  }
  _onEventB(event: Event) {
    if (!this.props.onEventA) {
      return;
    }
    this.props._onEventB(event.nativeEvent.myError);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <CustomView
        {...this.props}
        onEventA={this._onEventA}
        onEventB={this._onEventB}
      />
    );
  }
}

MyCustomView.propTypes = {
  htmlInjection: React.PropTypes.string,
  onEventA: React.PropTypes.func,
  onEventB: React.PropTypes.func,
};

var CustomView = requireNativeComponent('CustomView', MyCustomView);

module.exports = MyCustomView;

// CustomWrapperContainer.js

class CustomWrapperContainer extends React.Component {

  api: Object;
  constructor (props: Object) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      htmlInjection: '',
      myDataA: 'Some placeholder text'
    };

    this.api = RestApi.create();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='position'>
          <Text>{this.state.myDataA}</Text>
          <MyCustomView
            style={styles.myStyle}
            htmlInjection={this.state.htmlInjection}
            onEventA={this.handleEventA.bind(this)}
            onEventB={this.handleEventB.bind(this)}
          />
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </View>
    )
  }

  handleEventA = (data) => {
    console.log('on Event A', data);
    this.setState({myDataA: data})
  };

  handleEventB = (error) => {
    console.log('On Event B', error);
  };
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CustomWrapperContainer)
```

I have followed the [example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html#events) from `React Native` itself and also several others, but I have had no luck so far in getting an event to pass from `iOS` to `React Native`. Neither have I been able to find significant help in this matter from existing articles.

`Ignite` uses `react` version `15.3.2`. Perhaps that's the issue? Or the version of some other dependency there? I'm not sure. I'd greatly appreciate any help or leads.

P.S.: I've been running this on both devices and simulators running `iOS 9.2` through `10.0` and I don't see any change in behaviour, so that's not the issue.

Comment: the first thing I think about when seeing this, is make sure to consider trying v2 of RNWebview bridge.  This will be landing in RN Master soon:  https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge/tree/v2

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand how this is related to the issue I am having. I do have a webView that I load HTML content in and that works fine. It's only when I try to pass back data via callbacks that the communication doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't see anything wrong with this code so I was hoping to supply some additional info.  Do you have this code in a repo I could access?

Comment: Ah I'm afraid that code has access restrictions. But I am planning to run the same code in a pure react native project to confirm this isn't an ignite thing. Do you have any other theories or suggestions about what I could do to debug this?

Comment: @GantMan I've posted an answer and the approach works. Any comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, so given that `RCTBubblingEventBlock` and `RCTDirectEventBlock` seem to be broken, I had to find another approach for passing callbacks into `JS` code. So I found that the approach taken for `Android` with event emitters seemed promising and I did find that `iOS` has an `RCTEventEmitter` object which I could use.

After a lot of playing/looking around, I found this [`gist`](https://gist.github.com/andybangs) which helped me build my communication from `iOS` to `JS`. It did not feel clean, and there was a lot more code to write to get it set up, but it worked in the end. I hope it stays that way.

I also hope that the recommended method of using `RCTBubblingEventBlock` and `RCTDirectEventBlock` works at some point!

Comment: wow!  Thanks for researching and discovering this!  I had no idea.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into a different issue with `RCTBubblingEventBlock`. All `RCTBubblingEventBlock` must be prefixed with `on`. This is not currently noted under the documentation.

For example:

```
onMyEvent //will work
myEvent   //no good
```

Comment: Thanks @Ulises, you saved my day. :)

Answer (score 3):

This answer might come late, but I hope it would help.

Firstly thanks for your research. I also stuck in the same problem as yours and then I had to use RCTEventEmitter as your answer.

But later I double-checked and reviewed my code, I found some points that help my code running well with RCTBubblingEventBlock.

I saw that you using

```
MyCustomView.propTypes = {
  htmlInjection: React.PropTypes.string,
  onEventA: React.PropTypes.func,
  onEventB: React.PropTypes.func,
```

and

```
<CustomView
        {...this.props}
        onEventA={this._onEventA}
        onEventB={this._onEventB}
      />
```

The block {...this.props} will set all props of MyCustomView to CustomView. In another view if onEventA and onEventB of MyCustomView are configured then onEventA and onEventB of CustomView will have the same value because of {...this.props}.

Try to remove this in property define code of MyCustomView

```
onEventA: React.PropTypes.func,
onEventB: React.PropTypes.func,
```

Or you can use the config property for native only code in React-native MapView example

```
const RCTMap = requireNativeComponent('RCTMap', MapView, {
  nativeOnly: {
    onAnnotationDragStateChange: true,
    onAnnotationFocus: true,
    onAnnotationBlur: true,
    onChange: true,
    onPress: true
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @khanhha! That solution seems promising. I wish you'd come along a month ago, it would've been really helpful. But I'm sure this solution will be useful to me in the future as well. :)